# Debugging Polygon Approximation Algorithm Code C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, opengl, polygon

I was wondering if it would be possible for you to help me debug some code of mine. I've written the following code for a class project where we are implementing a polygon approximation algorithm. But I can't seem to get the code to do what I'd like for it to do. Here's a link to a wiki article of the algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm

The problem I'm having is that the second array, closedStack either isn't having the values inside updated properly, or it's not being displayed properly. But the first array, the one that is read in from the file displays properly. I also kept getting the closedStack error of it being full, so I changed the if statements to not use the fileSize variable so that may also have an issue with it. If you need me to explain any of the logic or variables, etc, just ask and I'll explain.

```
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "glut.h"

using namespace std;

struct point{
    int x, y;
};

void display(void);
void fileRead();
void oPush(point);
void cPush(point);
point oPop();
int deviation();

point pixel[2000];
int fileSize = 0;
int errorAllowed= 5;
int errorDeviation=0;
int oTop = 0;
int cTop = 0;
point first;
point last;
point openStack[5000];
point closedStack[5000];
int V1 = 0;
int V2 = 0;

void main(int argc, char **argv){

    fileRead();

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(75,75);
    glutCreateWindow("Ramer's Iterative Algorithm");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    gluOrtho2D(0,500,0,500);

    fileSize = fileSize/2;

    int tmp1 = pixel[0].x+pixel[0].y;
    int tmp2 = 0;


    for(int i = 0; i<2000; i++){
        tmp2 = pixel[i].x+pixel[i].y;

        if(tmp2 < tmp1){
            tmp1 = tmp2;
            V1 = i;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<2000; i++){
        tmp2 = pixel[i].x+pixel[i].y;

        if(tmp2 > tmp1){
            tmp1 = tmp2;
            V2 = i;
        }
    }

    oPush(pixel[V1]);
    oPush(pixel[V2]);
    oPush(pixel[V1]);

    do{
        first = oPop();
        last = oPop();

        int Mid = deviation();

        if(errorDeviation>errorAllowed){
            oPush(last);
            oPush(pixel[Mid]);
            oPush(first);
        }

        else if(errorDeviation<=errorAllowed){
            oPush(last);
            cPush(first);
        }

    }while(oTop>=2);

    glutMainLoop();

    cin >> V1;

}

void display(void){
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1,1,1);

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for(int i=0; i<2000; i++)
        glVertex2i(pixel[i].x,pixel[i].y);
    glEnd();

    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for(int i=0;i<=cTop; i++)
        glVertex2i(closedStack[i].x,closedStack[i].y);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

void fileRead(){
    char fileName[20];

    cout << "Enter the name of the file you would like to parse data from: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    ifstream boundary;
    boundary.open(fileName);
    if(boundary.fail()){
        cout << "Could not open '" << fileName << "' for reading.\n";
        exit(0);
    }

    for(int i=0; !boundary.eof(); i++){
        boundary >> pixel[i].x;
        boundary >> pixel[i].y;
        fileSize ++;
    }

}

void oPush(point p){
    if(oTop>fileSize){
        cout << "Full Stack--Open\n";
        exit(0);
    }

    else{
        oTop++;
        openStack[oTop]= p;
    }
}

void cPush(point p){
    if(cTop>10000){
        cout << "Full Stack--Closed\n";
        exit(0);
    }

    else{
        cTop++;
        closedStack[cTop]= p;
    }
}

point oPop(){
    point temp;

    if(oTop<=0){
        cout << "Stack Empty\n";
        exit(0);
    }

    else{
        temp = pixel[oTop];
        oTop--;
    }
    return temp;
}

int deviation(){
    float y = last.y-first.y;
    float x = last.x-first.x;
    float theta = atan(y/x);
    int most = 0;

    for(int i = V1+1; i < V2; i++){
        float ped = (-(pixel[i].x-first.x)*sin(theta))+((pixel[i].y-last.y)*cos(theta));
        float errDev= abs(ped);

        if(errDev>most)
            most = i;
        errorDeviation = (int)errDev;
    }

    return most;
}
```

To elaborate on V1 and V2, they are supposed to be the bottom left and top right most points of the array. The loop that checks I've simplified to:

```
for(int i = 0; i<fileSize; i++){
tmp2 = (pixel[i].x)+(pixel[i].y);

if(tmp2 <= tmp1){
    tmp1 = tmp2;
    V1 = i;
}

if(tmp2 >= tmp1){
    tmp1 = tmp2;
    V2 = i;
}
```

The loop adds the point's x+y together, and then checks it against the previous point to update it. The point with the lowest x+y should end up being V1 and the highest should be V2. But I don't think the loop is functioning properly. By zooming in on what get's drawn, the second portion of the display loop only has three points. It looks like the first and second point of the initial array as well as 0,0 get plotted. Not sure why that's happening.

Comment: What is the significance of V1 and V2? Why is your starting stack [V1, V2, V1]? Is `deviation()` intended to cope with V2 < V1? Have you tried implementing the recursive algorithm described on Wikipedia already? Even if you require to write a non-recursive version, it's probably easier to implement the recursive one first and then you'll have that as a reference to compare the behaviour of your stack-based one.

Comment: So V1 and V2 are the index number of the start and end pixel of the line segment that Mid is checked against for the deviation. The stack starts like that because those are the initial three points of the approximation. The algorithm then adds more to the closed stack which then becomes the new set of points to be plotted. 

I haven't implemented the recursive version, no. But I don't have time to really. This project is due too soon for me to do so. Just trying to get the code I already have working so that I can turn in for partial credit.

Comment: Frankly, this code has a *lot* of problems. Give us the simplest example you can think of that shows the error (input data and what you expect `closedStack` to be), and maybe we can help.

Comment: You mean give an example of points and what the resulting stack should be using the algorithm on them? I can try to do that. The math is slightly complex though. And not sure if I'd be able to really help with just text comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, your question is really too broad. You need to make some attempt to narrow it down yourself. Here's a good checklist: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx

You will not fix your problem by trying to write a complete working program in one shot. Visual output is invaluable, but it cannot replace textual output of the actual list of points. Your question and comments suggest that you're trying to debug this just by looking at the final visual output. You need to break this down into smaller pieces and look at the data in between each step so that you can understand where your program is diverging from your expectation.

As you say "the second array, closedStack either isn't having the values inside updated properly, or it's not being displayed properly". The first step to solving this problem is to find out which of these is the case! Does the array have the wrong values, or is it being displayed incorrectly? You can find that out by printing out the intermediate values and comparing them to what you expect when you solve the problem by hand. If the input is too large, create a smaller set of input points that you can work with by hand. Once you have narrowed it down you will either find that you can solve the problem yourself or that you have a much more focused question to ask that will elicit better answers.

---

From a rough inspection, I'd guess:

1. It seems likely you are misunderstanding the input. You haven't described what it is. If it's a sequence of points that form a [piece-wise linear curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) then it's not clear why it would be helpful to pick out the elements that are southwest-most and northeast-most (assuming east is +ve x and north +ve y). If it's a cloud of points then you'll need to do more than just pick out the corners to get the rest in a meaningful order.
2. It seems your function `deviation()` makes the assumption that index *first* is less than index *last*. But there appears to be nothing to guarantee this. For a start, perhaps V1 has a greater index than V2. Even if it doesn't, you populate the initial stack with [V1, V2, V1], guaranteeing that `deviation()` will see inputs where `first` > `last`. While I'm certainly not going to guarantee that there's nothing wrong with `deviation()`, my guess is that there is a problem with what you're feeding into it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've been doing little cout's here and there trying to figure out variables, and it's helping. I'll work on it some more and maybe post again once I've got something more specific.

Comment: The input to the program is a set of pixels whose coordinates are stored in a text file. The pixels make up a curved shape with a closed boundary. I can pass it any shape, but for testing, I'm just using a simple circle. The reason for picking SW an NE points is to get the points roughly in half. I can do any two points along the boundary, but I couldn't think of a simple loop to figure out other points along the boundary. I can't just pick the first and middle point as this is an assignment, and so the teacher assigned us to do either SW and NE or NW and SE.

Comment: I see what you mean now about the deviation function. What I'm trying to make it do is to test the deviation from the line with endpoints V1 and V2 for every single point of the array between those two indexes. Can you suggest an easier way to cycle through the indexes between V1 and V2 that would not be affected by one being bigger than the other?

Comment: Hmm, I misread it. Do you really mean to cycle through all the points between V1 and V2 every time? Surely you only mean to cycle through the points between `first` and `last`? It's not clear what you mean to do when they're in reverse order... Do you mean to continue on around the perimeter of the circle in the same direction? In that case you might read up on the <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation">modulus/remainder</a> operator "`%`", and consider a more appropriate end condition for your loop, perhaps "i != last" rather than "i < last".

Comment: Yea, that's what I meant. The deviation function should only scan the indexes from first to last. But first and last are point variables, they don't have an index number associated with them. How would I use a pointer to access that data? Because first and last are also not part of the initial array. They are just the top two of the openStack. So I somehow need to keep track of which ones first and last are in that initial array.

Comment: You're right, first and last are not indexes. So it seems you'll need to change the specification for `deviation()`, as there's insufficient information there for it to do its job. I hope I don't come across as mean - you have been very polite, and you've done a good job giving context for your problem - but your questions are very vague and you've not made clear what effort you've made to diagnose the problem yourself. Stack Overflow isn't a good forum for mentoring and tutorials. Feel free to ask new questions, but bear in mind the need to be specific.

Comment: No problem. I'm just going to turn in the assignment in how it is and get some partial credit for it. I waited too long to try and recode the entire thing, and I was real rusty so it took me forever to get just this mess coded. I really appreciate the help though.